boto3 redshift client .describe_statement provides no error message
I've run an sql query through boto3 redshift client's execute_statement function, and subsequently checked the status of the query with describe_statement.
result = client_redshift.execute_statement(Database= 'my_database', SecretArn= secret_arn,
                                           Sql= query_str, ClusterIdentifier= cluster_id, 
                                           ResultFormat = "CSV")    

response = client_redshift.describe_statement(Id = result["Id"])
if response["Status"] == "FINISHED":
   data = client_redshift.get_statement_result(Id = result["Id"])
   break
if response["Status"] == "FAILED":
   print(response.keys())

The status comes out as failed, and I'm trying to figure out why. The SQL is fine, I've checked it in another app.
According to boto3 1.35.79 documentation, there should be "Error" in the keys returned by describe_statement, but there is not.
Boto3 documentation:

Result of response.keys():
dict_keys(['ClusterIdentifier', 'CreatedAt', 'Database', 'Duration', 'HasResultSet', 'Id', 'QueryString', 'RedshiftPid', 'RedshiftQueryId', 'ResultFormat', 'ResultRows', 'ResultSize', 'SecretArn', 'Status', 'UpdatedAt', 'ResponseMetadata'])

Before I report this as an issue on Github, am I missing something here?

Well, if that's definitely the version you're using then I'd say the documentation isn't correct
